# Getting friend email and phone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am pretty new to facebook development and am trying to accomplish the following requirement for a banking site.

1. I need to get the list of facebook friends of a logged in user and
   display the same in a drop down box
2. User will select one friend and transfer funds to the same
3. I need to send an email/SMS/private FB message to the selected
   friend with some details.

I can used the `taggable_friends` node to get all the friends list and show them in a drop down. Is there any way to accomplish the third point? As far as I have seen, I need the unencrypted facebook id to accomplish this which is not available in any of the graph API nodes.

Can someone please help if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

`taggable_friends` is for tagging only, you are not allowed to use it for anything else. More information about the possibilities for getting access to user friends: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

About part 3: You can´t send a FB message with the API, the Chat API is deprecated. You can use the Send Dialog though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

If you just want to send an E-Mail, just use PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

For SMS, there are plenty of services, usually with a limited amount of free SMS.

Keep in mind that you can´t get email or phone from a friend with the Facebook API at all. That was never possible and friend permissions are deprecated. The user needs to enter the E-Mail, phone number or Facebook Account (if you use the Send Dialog).

Comment: You were a few seconds faster :-)  it was never possible to get the phone number and the email address of friends...

Answer (score 0):

The use of `taggable_friends` is a misuse in this case IMHO. You should use `/me/friends`, which only return the friends which also use the app. You cannot use the `user-taggable-friend` for anything else than displaying.

Furthermore, as the `friends_*` permissions have been deprecated, you can't receive the email or the phone number anymore. The latter was never possible anyway.

See the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/

Comment: Thanks. Can I share a message/URL on my wall and share the same with a friend? Is there any way to set the facebook id of that friend through API?